# Android version in Android Studio causes app to crash on some phones?

Tags: apk, system-error

I have developed recently a simple app using Android Studio and I was able to run/upload it while working on the code on my Samsung Galaxy S4. At the end, I built an APK file, and sent it to a friend of mine. The person was able to install it, but when trying to open it the error "Unfortunately, the APP has stopped" appeared.

So now I have two Android phones in front. One in which the app works and another which has that error. Same code!

I assume that there is problem with the versions (the working phone has Android 4.4.2 and the one that is not working has Android 6.0.1). In Android Studio, I chose API:15 Android 4.0.3 (IceCream Sandwich) because, according to AS, should work on all the phone (see picture blow).

[image]

Now, can anyone help me to figure out if the version is the one causing the app to work on one phone, but not on the other? It's the only thing I can think of right now, as the code works fine on one of them. And if it is the version, is it possible to change it now, after writing the code? And finally, is there any APK conversion algorithm that might be responsible for this?

Comment: Development questions are off-topic on this site. You may ask it on [so], instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue which you are facing is most likely being caused due to the requirement of permissions. In devices running Android 6.0 (API level 23) and above, runtime permissions are required for 'dangerous' permissions. Simply adding them in your Android Manifest is not sufficient... the app needs to explicitly request them from the user. Since you are facing the issue with Android 6.0.1, this is the most probable reason.
You can read about this here:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html